# CSS transition with nested classes

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I am trying to create animation using pure CSS.
Here is my html structure

```
 <div class="portfolio-item col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3" data-groups='["all", "identety", "interface"]'>
              <div class="portfolio-bg">
                <div class="portfolio">
                  <div class="tt-overlay"></div>
                  <div class="links">
                    <a class="image-link" href="images/works/portfolio-1.jpg"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>                          
                  </div><!-- /.links -->
                  <img class="portfolio-image" src="images/works/portfolio-1.jpg" alt="image"> 
                  <div class="portfolio-info">
                    <h3>Portfolio Title</h3>
                  </div><!-- /.portfolio-info -->
                </div><!-- /.portfolio -->
              </div><!-- /.portfolio-bg -->
            </div><!-- /.portfolio-item -->
```

And my CSS styles

```
@imageHoverRotationAngle : 10deg;
@imageHoverScaleValue : 1.5;
@imageHoverAnimationTime : 0.5s;

.portfolio:hover .tt-overlay, 
.portfolio:hover .links {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
    -o-transform: translate(0,0);
    transform: translate(0,0);
}
.portfolio:hover .portfolio-image {
      -webkit-transform:rotate(@imageHoverRotationAngle) scale(@imageHoverScaleValue);
      -moz-transform:rotate(@imageHoverRotationAngle) scale(@imageHoverScaleValue);
      -ms-transform:rotate(@imageHoverRotationAngle) scale(@imageHoverScaleValue);
      -o-transform:rotate(@imageHoverRotationAngle) scale(@imageHoverScaleValue);
      transform:rotate(@imageHoverRotationAngle) scale(@imageHoverScaleValue);
}
.portfolio .portfolio-image {
       -webkit-transition:all @imageHoverAnimationTime ease-out;
      -moz-transition:all @imageHoverAnimationTime ease-out;
      -ms-transition:all @imageHoverAnimationTime ease-out;
      -o-transition:all @imageHoverAnimationTime ease-out;
      transition:all @imageHoverAnimationTime ease-out;
}
```

I cannot get it working.

In this case only `portfolio-image` is being animated, if css animation styles for `portfolio-image` than `tt-overlay` and `links` will work.

Is it possible to achieve both animations `tt-overlay`,`links` and `portfolio-image` at the same time ?

Comment: You haven't assigned any `transition` property to the other two. Did you try applying it?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps a **minimal** demo might be helpful here?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set initial opacity for your elements and every animated element should have transition property. + your example is a little bit empty without values.

Here is a plunker. I've added some values, so you can see changes. It's in Sass, but no a big difference.

```
.portfolio .tt-overlay, .portfolio .links { opacity: 0; }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ll29vpEkifg68W0yvaal?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, I have such class with zero opacity. As I said it works without image animation

Comment: But my plunker is working and it resemble your case. What browser do you use?